# ng-class validation is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I tried to put green background if it is edited and valid.

But, even for invalid also it is showing green background. On invalid it should show the yellow background with red text.

Thanks in advance for giving me the solution.

#### html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">

    <form name="inputform">
        <div ng-class="{'has-success': inputform.email.$dirty && inputform.email.$valid, 'has-error': inputform.email.$dirty && inputform.email.$invalid}">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="data.email" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
        </div>
    </form>

    {{data}}

</div>
```

#### javascript

```
var module = angular.module("myApp", []);

module.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.data = {};

}]);
```

#### css

```
.has-error {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
}

.has-success {
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You didn't add any validation constraints, so what is *invalid* you expect then? Of course, it's always valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no validation applied to that input element so it is valid all the time. Try the below form, I've applied the `required` and `email` validation:

(It will only be green if a proper email address in entered)

```js
var module = angular.module("myApp", []);

module.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.data = {};

}]);
```

```css
.has-error {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
}

.has-success {
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">

    <form name="inputform">
        <div ng-class="{'has-success': inputform.email.$valid, 'has-error': inputform.email.$invalid}">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required ng-model="data.email" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
        </div>
    </form>

    {{data}}

</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use [this](https://github.com/sagrawal14/bootstrap-angular-validation) library to provide Bootstrap form validation in simple way.

Comment: Thank you very much Shashank. it is working exactly.